# Windows 11 file explorer performance for large number of files

Tags: performance, windows-explorer

I'm recently handling folders with a large number of small files(around 50,000 files in the same directory, each about 1kB~100kB) and notice that operations are extremely slow. For example, simply selecting 20K files will take the system around 5~10 minutes to respond.

I don't see a high CPU or IO usage for such operation. Also command line operations are as fast as usual so I think the problem lies in file explorer. How can I improve the performance in this situation?

EDIT: Drives are Intel Optane 905p and system has 64G RAM. Files are either gzip files or json files.

Comment: What kind of hard drive? What kinds of files? How much RAM?

Comment: @music2myear Intel Optane drives and 64G RAM. Files are general gzip files but I don't think it matters here?

Comment: @hyyyyy - We wouldn't be asking if we didn't think it was relevant.  So can you [edit] your question to include that information instead of submitting a comment?

Comment: @Ramhound You are right. I asked because at a first glance the type of files should not affect performance. Later I realized some special files may need extra system power, e.g. picture previews.

Comment: `How can I improve the performance in this situation?` Split the files into many folders (e.g. based on the first letter(s) of the filename). 50 folders containing 1000 files each should load fast. 10 folders containing 5000 files each would already be much faster.

Comment: Yeah, splitting into subfolders is definitely the way to go. If first letter is not an option, consider splitting based on creation or modify date. A powershell script can automate this task for you.